# Why does Magento2 add 0.0001 in the credit memo refund processing?

Tags: magento2

I am talking about the file

> vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Creditmemo/Total/Shipping.php

here in codes

```
if ($desiredAmount < $this->priceCurrency->round($maxAllowedAmount) + 0.0001) {
```

And

```
if ($desiredAmount > $maxAllowedAmount - 0.0001) {
```

why is there addition and subtraction of the amount 0.0001

Can't this be done without this?

Comment: I think the comments in the code explain it : *Note: ($x < $y + 0.0001) means ($x <= $y) for floats*

Comment: Yes I have seen the comments, why not use  directly `$x <= $y. `
I never experienced issues in any float values this way either.

Comment: you can override this file in your custom module to meet your desired criteria

Comment: @Pramod yes I understand that. And I feel my question is not clear... I am just asking why have Magento creators opted for this way of solving the problem, Must be some big reason...
Want to know that reason.

Comment: Any magento official here?